# How not to update bootstrap typeahead input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using Twitter typeahead for showing search results. When a suggested result is selected say using arrow key, the default behaviour is to update the search input with the result.

I don't want the search input to get updated with the selected result, i.e. it should continue to show what the user had typed.

Comment: Please, Can you create a custom fiddle because on this one, there is no problem http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ncZJn/

Comment: Its solved here https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/884